# How to detach this faucet sprayer? Photos included

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-sink

I want to install an extra add on to the sprinkler head, but I'm not sure how do I detach this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to add to it?

Comment: The connections on pull-out faucet spray heads and hoses are usually a proprietary size and thread. Unless this "add-on" was made specifically for your faucet it will probably not work.

Comment: Uh oh, I'll detach the head and have a look. This add-on is not made for the faucet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't just turn? If not, then I'd guess you depress that little tab with the circle and then turn it.

*Righty tighty, lefty loosey.*

Comment: Remember that the original equipment was designed to prevent *siphoning*. Anti-siphon features prevent contamination of your (and everyone else's) drinking water. Changing to an aftermarket device *could* affect (or eliminate) that feature.